# How to get wifi signal strength using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

So far I am able to scan all the available wifi using QNetworkConfigurationManager::allConfigurations(), but the QNetworkConfiguration data for each of them does not have the wifi signal strength. Can you point me into how to get this data? Thanks!

Comment: which platform are you targeting?

Comment: Target OS = Windows 8. I'm using Qt 4.8.4 with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I think that will require native code.

Comment: Just now I found about QSystemNetworkInfo::networkSignalStrength(QSystemNetworkInfo::WlanMode). But I'm still clueless on how to use this on a given QNetworkConfiguration. Can you give me a hint here?

Comment: It looks like this function can only return the signal strength of the currently used network connection, i.e. you must be connected to it.

Comment: @TimMeyer yes indeed. What I want is to enumerate all the wifi hotspots, then get the signal strength from each one through some API.

Comment: @aaa: `QSystemNetworkInfo` are part of the Mobility frameworks, whilst you can get them to run on a desktop OS they're not guaranteed to run correctly. You may find it easier to actually go for native system code to get the signal strength.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs, I decided to try the mobility framework first, since we already have it integrated on another related project. I'll fallback to the native wifi api if this proved to be not reliable.

Answer (score 3):

You could use QProcess and run command line commands to scan for wifi networks. Use regular expressions to parse the command line output which contains all details of the wifi network.

If you are using linux then the command is "iwlist scan"

Comment: nowadays it is `iw wlan0 scan` :-) This is the way, I'm testing WLAN cards in Qt.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you even can do this on normal desktop anyway(i mean just using Qt). Qt just dont have common interface with device to get such things. I am not sure what OS you are using, but the best hit for you is linking with OS and getting info from it or talking to device directly via driver. Both methods are difficult, especially because you need documentations, and moreover:

- For the first method, linking via driver - this will work only for specific driver unless signal strenght is reported in way common to many drivers.
- For the second method, linking via system - there may be slight difference between linux distros that can make you unable to make app portable between them. Same goes for Windows an linux, there is no guarantee(i would even say "way" but I am not sure so...) that both systems uses those same methods to report signal strength for user.

whatever you decide to do, you can use standard OS features to complete the goal. For example in windows you can use `WlanGetAvailableNetworkList()`. As far as I remember it will will provide something called `IRSSI` which is direct signal strength indicator :)

enjoy :)