# how do you connect to a Wireless WIFI Network in QT or windows API?

Tags: c++, windows, api, qt

is there any APIs for detecting wireless networks? ,  or any QT class for detecting wireless networks and connecting to them . `QNetworkInterface` is the closest class but it does not support it .

Comment: Look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651410/how-to-get-wifi-signal-strength-using-qt)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`QNetworkConfigurationManager`](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qnetworkconfigurationmanager.html) and [`QNetworkSession`](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qnetworksession.html)

```
QNetworkConfiguration cfg;
QNetworkConfigurationManager ncm;
auto nc = ncm.allConfigurations();

for (auto &x : nc)
{
    if (x.bearerType() == QNetworkConfiguration::BearerWLAN)
    {
        if (x.name() == "YouDesiredNetwork")
            cfg = x;
    }
}

auto session = new QNetworkSession(cfg, this);
session->open();
```

It first searches for the network with you desired name and then tries to connect to it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `allConfigurations` returns a list of network interfaces for me, not networks / SSID